# How to look for a value in a sheet, but it may be in different columns, and the copy pasted in another sheet if match some criteria?

Tags: vba, excel

here is my issue. 
I have 2 sheets in the same workbook that share a common criteria (po#). 
*Sheet1: contains the information that has to be filtered and divided according to sheet3... that is if the PO# in sheet1 match the po# in sheet3 then the whole row should be copy and pasted in a "sheet4" if meets some criteria ("market" that could be jet, bigcommerce, amazon). Here is where it gets more complicated...
1-the po# in sheet3 is in the first column (A), but the po# in sheet1 is in column A or B.
2-The idea is to have one sheet for each market.
So excel should look for the po# first, and the if its there, look for "market" and copy paste all the records that share the same market in another sheet. 
*Sheet3: contains po# and some other data.

--Other user asked a similar question (find record and copy pasted in another sheet) but the answer is based on the lookup value being in only one column (as opposed to my case where it may be in A or B). how can I make it look in both columns?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your two search columns are in the same data table as your results, your solution is actually quite straightforward, using a combination of the INDEX & MATCH functions. INDEX pulls in the value for a column, for a specified row #. MATCH provides the row number, where a search term was found in a column. Together, they work like this, pulling in the amount in column D, for the row where column B matches the search term in A1:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

For your case, you simply need to use IFERROR to first try to match the search term in one column, and then if no match is found, try to match the search term in a second column. Put this formula in your sheet1, starting at B2 [assuming no headers], and then drag down and to the right:

```
=INDEX('Sheet3'!B:B,IFERROR(MATCH('Sheet1'$A2,'Sheet3'!$A:$A,0),MATCH('Sheet1'$A2,'Sheet3'!$B:$B,0)))
```